# How to write an `std::istream` operator

Tags: c++, parsing, stream

How do I write a function that reads an `std::istream` and sets proper flags if the stream contained unexpected content, ended before expected, or was not fully consumed?

For concreteness, suppose I'm expecting the stream to contain a string of alpha characters followed by a separator and then some digits, like `foo:55`. I'd like to read something like

```
struct var {
  std::string name;
  double value;
};
```

from the stream. I can of course write the operator as

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, var& x) {
  std::string str;
  s >> str;
  size_t sep = str.find(':');
  x.name  = str.substr(0,sep);
  x.value = atof(str.substr(sep+1).c_str());
  return s;
}
```

But can I do without copying the stream content to a string? Also, this doesn't work with spaces, in the sense that `str` won't contain the whole stream content.

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30960498/2640636) about a week ago, but there was no response to it, probably because I framed it in context on `boost::program_options` and such questions don't seem to get much attention here.

Comment: Are you looking for `std::getline(s, x.name, ':');` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::getline` instead of `s >> str` to read up to `':'`, and then read the number directly into the `double`, like this:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, var& x) {
    // Skip over the leading whitespace
    while (s.peek() == '\n' || s.peek() == ' ') {
        s.get();
    }
    std::getline(s, x.name, ':');
    s >> x.value;
    return s;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/FLFeuX)

Comment: Perhaps add an `if(s.eof())` statement to address the concern that it ends before expected.

Comment: @R_Kapp The current code appears to work fine even when there is not enough input (see link at the demo, I added a partial line at the end, and it gets ignored).

Comment: I meant more in terms of error trapping (e.g. print out a "Hey you screwed up!" message) and was intended more at the OP than you... sorry should have been clearer on that. Apparently, also had a typo (ended with a "?" instead of a ".", which made my comment even more misleading...)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Your solution is adding a newline to the front of every string after the first input.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was wondering myself about the larger than expected gaps in my demo, thanks for explaining the reason!

Comment: @nathanoliver: you probably want to skip whitespace before calling getline.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: OPs solution skips whitespace before (as part of s >> str), not afterwards. So Nathan's solution does not match that behaviour.

Comment: @rici Ah, you're right. I didn't pay attention, thinking that OP used `getline`.

Comment: Also, you can use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/sentry to skip whitespace, rather than hardcoding the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I didn't know there was a `getline` overload that reads until a specific character.

Comment: Is there to read until a specific character and parse, without copying the substring to a temporary `string`?

Comment: @SU3 This solution does not use temporary strings, writing directly to data members of your `struct`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight what if I had two colon separated integers?

Comment: @SU3 Then you would need to do another loop similar to the first one, i.e. `while (s.peek() == ':'`)...`

Answer (score 1):

Why not let the stream do the work for you.  You can use [`getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), `>>` and [istream::ignore()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to read in the input.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, var& x) {
    // get the string part and through out the :
    std::getline(s, x.name, ':');
    // get the number part
    s >> x.value;
    // consume the newline so the next call to getline won't include it in the string part
    s.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
    return s;
}
```